# Escape # in excel formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using Excel 2010 on Windows 7. I have a VBA macro which have to put a formula under a table in Excel 2010. The table is a ListObject with column names [Date], [Traffic, MB] and [Requests, #]
I use the following code to add the formulas:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("myquery1").Range
    .Columns(2).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = "=SUM(myquery1[Traffic, MB])"
    .Columns(3).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = "=SUM(myquery1[Requests, #])"
End With
```

An error appears on the line with formula "=SUM(myquery1[Requests, #])". 
The error is "Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"
No errors appear for formulas which do not have the character #

Is there a way to escape this character?

Comment: If you could [provide a way to reproduce this](http://www.sscce.org/) it would make life easier for us trying to solve your problem

Comment: Untested, but have you tried simply offseting the character in quotation marks?  `"=SUM(myquery1[Requests, " & """#""" & "])"  Otherwise, what are you actually trying to obtain with this formula? What does the `#` mean in context, to *you*?

Comment: in this example # represents the measurement unit of "requests". It means number of requests, and the other column is "Traffic" measured in megabytes. The users of this macro used to see it this way. The purpose of this formula is to give the totals of all values in a specific column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to find the answer. Escaping # in excel formula is done with an apostrophe '

The formula has to be:

```
 "=SUM(myquery1[Requests, '#])"
```